# AWS MQTT on Node-RED / IBM Cloud Boilerplate App

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, node-red, aws-iot

Is there any reason that you shouldn't be able to connect to the AWS MQTT broker from Node-RED instance on the IBM Cloud (created via Boilerplate apps)?

> Config of MQTT input node/ Server config...

```
Server: xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com / 8883  
[x] Enable secure connection  
(key and certificates uploaded)  
[x] Verify server certificate  
Client ID: IBM  
Kepp alive time 60s  
[x] Use clean session  

Topic: #  
QoS: 2
```

Node is status is 'disconnected'

```
2018-04-24T13:46:38.11+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 24 Apr 11:46:38 - [info] [mqtt-broker:AWS] Connected to broker: IBMNodeRed@mqtts://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:8883
2018-04-24T13:46:38.12+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 24 Apr 11:46:38 - [info] [mqtt-broker:AWS] Disconnected from broker: IBMNodeRed@mqtts://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:8883
```

Cycles through these info logs every 15 seconds.

Comment: Please add information about your configurations or code

Comment: I mean edit your question to include the code and configurations of the connection you are trying to make

Comment: Sorry, started here then realised that was the correct way.

Comment: Do the Node-RED logs show any errors?

Comment: Need a little help getting to the log in IBM cloud. From windows terminal `bx cf logs <app-name>`. Where exactly do I get the app name from? Tried the obvious ones.

Comment: Removed the spaces from the app name and allowed me to check logs. Added above.